# How to parse xml file in my junit selenium test case using eclipse

Tags: java, xml, junit, selenium, selenium-rc

How to parse xml file in my junit selenium test case using eclipse, I want to grab data from this file and insert it in forms using my selenium RC test case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [dom4j](http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/), and this is my approach. I implemented a selenium + Junit framework and all the data inputs are in XML format. So I setup the structure of the xml input. So If you are going on this direction I would advise you to identify what xml format/structure.

Example:

```
<seleniumtest>

    <!-- Selenium Test Parameters -->

    <Parameter name="inputValue">
        <value>myvalue</value>
    </Parameter>     

    <Parameter name="mypassword">
        <value>password</value>
    </Parameter>

    <Parameter name="users">
        <value>user1</value>
        <value>user2</value>       
    </Parameter>

</seleniumtest>
```

One you finalize on the structure you can start writing a parse and expose the data into rest of the test or just for a one test.

Here is the start for your xml parser, Create a class and have the constructor read in the xml file,

```
public class XMLFileParser {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(XMLFileParser.class.getName());

    private Document document;

    /**
     * Method will construct a Document Object from the given InputStream
     * @param readIn The input stream to read the document.
     */
    public XMLFileParser(InputStream readIn) {
        SAXReader reader = new SAXReader();
        try {
            document = reader.read(readIn);
        }catch (DocumentException ex) {
            log.error("Error when attempting to parse input data file", ex);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Write a method to iterate over the nodes to actually parse the xml file. 
     */
    public HashMap<String, Object> parseInput(HashMap<String, Object> params) { 
        Element rootElement = document.getRootElement();
        for(Iterator iter = rootElement.elementIterator("Parameter"); iter.hasNext();) {
                // This where you should write your parse logic,  
             }

        return params;
    }
```

It doesn't have to be a hashmap but thats what I wanted to do you can make this method to return anything that you wish based on your framework.

Have Fun;

Answer (score 2):

Java has inbuilt machanism for dealing with XML processing. It has support for both DOM as well as SAX parsers.
You may want to have a look at http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JAXPIntro.html

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/